# Hibernate and store procedure / function auto entity discovery

Tags: hibernate, function, jpa, stored-procedures

I'm looking into calling a function on MS SQL but don't see any possibility of using the JPA Discover wizard 'entities from Tables' feature in Eclipse. It only sees views and tables, anyway of auto discovering the function or store procedure signature objects ?

Also, I'm not planning to use maven only Hibernate and make use of Named Queries, no xml mapping, no native SQL . The function or Proc logic uses multiple joins from multiple Databases.

Why do I have to specify a table in this example ?

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "callStockStoreProcedure",
    query = "CALL GetStocks(:stockCode)",
    resultClass = Stock.class
    )
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {
```

What if the proc joins on 3 tables across 3 DBs ? 
Thanks for any advice

Comment: Why do you think you have to specify the table name?

Comment: @Table(name = "stock") ?